# How to set dynamic value to a variable and use it for other test in robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

Suppose I have a generated random alphanumeric character in Test 1(or by using user defined keyword). Now I want to set that random generated value to a variable `${RandomName}` (see attached image) and use that variable for other test methods (say Test 2).

How would I go about doing this in Robot Framework?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyword [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) to make the variable accessible in every test in the current suite:

```
Set suite variable    ${RandomName}
```

There is also a keyword named [Set global variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable) which works in a similar manner but makes the variable available to all tests:

```
Set global variable    ${RandomName}
```

If you want to create a *new* variable that is visible everywhere you can do that with `Set Suite Variable` as well, passing the value as an additional argument.

```
Set suite variable    ${new variable}    hello, world
```

The above will create a varnamed named `${new variable}` and set it to the string `hello, world`.

Comment: Though your answer didn't address my question exactly on how I can set random generated value to a variable in robot framework, but it did help me in resolving my scenario exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar: I added some clarification. You can use the same keyword to make an existing variable available in a suite, but you can use the same keyword to create a new variable.

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar - Will you please provide exact solution to this and how you resolved it .I struck from 2 days  in exactly same scenario .Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: @ChiragDhingra I moved out from Jmeter project and currently into different roles and feel sorry that I cannot recollect the solution now as it's been long not doing anything related to Jmeter now. I should have posted answer that time itself.